# Set dynamically CSS :before attr with javascript

Tags: css, attr

I need to change dynamically the **left** property of a **css class** from a javascript function.

```
.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: **attr(data-left px)**;
    z-index: 10;
}

function DropDownHover() {
    try {
        $(".dropdown").hover(
            function () {
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown("400");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
                var objChevron = $(this).find(".fa-chevron-down");
                if (objChevron.length >0) {
                    var offset = $(this).find(".fa-chevron-down").offset();
                    var offsetBefore = offset.left - 273;
                    $('.mega-dropdown-menu').attr('data-left', offsetBefore);
                }
            },
            function () {
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp("400");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
            }
        );
    } catch (err) { alert(err.message); }
}
```

During the execution i get number of pixel and the **data-left** is set to the *div* but the offset is not being applied to the **left** property.

[image: Chrome inspector screenshot]

I also tried *attr(data-left number)* and *attr(data-left)*, all of them with the same result.

What am i missing?

Comment: here is your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin/49618941#49618941 (CSS variables)

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you can use `attr()` syntax only for `content` property.

Why not go

```
$('.mega-dropdown-menu').css('left', offsetBefore+'px');
```

?